# Can deleting the account of the person that installed the sql reportserver affect the ability to access report server from a c#/mvc website

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, report, reportserver

I am getting 'unauthorized' when accessing the reportserver from a website created with c#/mvc. I have tried every suggestion I could find on the internet with no luck. I can access reportserver from outside the network but when I try to call it through my program, I get unauthorized. Here is my code:

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
Uri("http://myserver/ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER14");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://myserver/ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER14");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reporting/" + rpt;
IReportServerCredentials creds = new CustomReportCredentials("userid", "pswd, "domain");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = creds;

ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[2];

param[0] = new ReportParameter("userid", useid, false);
param[1] = new ReportParameter("holdco", hldco, false);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);      (this is where it fails)
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Was told that because the original owner of the reportserver was deleted along with his password and authorizations, The only way to fix it was to remove and re-install reportserver. 
This worked perfectly until the report server owner was deleted.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are your custom report credentials the same as the person who was deleted?  You need to make sure those credentials have the authority to run reports from your server.

Comment: No. I have admin rights but the original password was a super user password and I do not have access to that, only the new manager has that password. I can run reports from inside but get error when running thru website.

Comment: Ok but you are passing in a set of credentials when you run the report - don;t you just need to change those credentials to a valid user who is allowed to run the reports?

Comment: We have tried creating an admin password and changing the credentials to match. no luck. Works just fine in the network but not from outside website. We have tried impersonate, but no luck either. No one knows what the original password was.

Comment: Do those credentials work if you access the Report Manager URL directly from a browser?  It's more likely that the new user hasn't been given the appropriate priviledges.

Comment: We can access reports manager from inside the network and a url outside. When we go through the website which is published we alway get the error. We have admin credentials and that is what is in the program calling the reportserver. we have used old passwords and tried new passwords. No matter what we do, we keep getting unauthorized. One consultant said the only way to solve it was to remove report server and do a full install using one of our current passwords to sign on to do the install. Just trying to see if any agrees or has other opinions.